# Load Style Before Transition?

Tags: css, button, transition

I have made a small log in button, but unfortunately, the transition loads before the width and color can, creating an ugly effect.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#login fieldset input[type="submit"] {  
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4px 0;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: `transition` transits _from_ one value _to_ another. Your posted code only shows the "original" (_from_) value. How are you applying the "transited" (_to_) value?

Comment: @Passerby I am using this for the to value: `#login fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background-color: #16a085;
} `

Comment: The transition seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9zDUv/

Comment: Well, try it here on my experimental website with chrome desktop, you'll see what I mean. http://sylau.gegahost.net/main

Comment: Still fine (Chrome 33). Can you be more specific on what's wrong?

Comment: Upon loading the page, the CSS sets the button background-color, color, and, (I think width) as the default value, as if half the style didn't load. It then proceeds to transit to the half that didn't load. This is observable upon a reload. If it still is working for your, I'll 1. Clear the cache( for the 4th time) and 2. Get a new host.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it

```
#login fieldset input[type="submit"] {  
    background-color: #1abc9c;
color: #fff;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 4px 0;
width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
transition: all 0.5s linear;

}
#login fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover{ background-color:#F00;}
```